# Remover todos os registros de uma tabela com Entity framework 6

Tags: c#, entity-framework

Como deletar todos os dados de uma tabela do banco usando o EF6 sem precisar fazer consulta (quero deletar todos os registros)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A maneira mais simples é:

```
context.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand("TRUNCATE TABLE [Tabela]");
```

Sim, esta não passa direto pelo Entity Framework. Para usar o Entity Framework explicitamente, o melhor é implementar uma extensão:

```
public static void ApagarTudo<T>(this DbSet<T> dbSet) where T : class
{
    dbSet.RemoveRange(dbSet);
}
```

Uso:

```
contexto.Entidades.ApagarTudo();
contexto.SaveChanges();
```

Answer (score 1):

Você pode usar o método ExecuteStoreQuery() do seu contexto passando um comando SQL para deletar todos os registros, veja o exemplo abaixo.

```
seuContexto.ExecuteStoreQuery("delete SuaTabela");
```

Para mais detalhes acesse o link abaixo
https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/vstudio/dd487208(v=vs.100).aspx